# Override phtml file recently viewed products in magento 2

Tags: magento2, recently-viewed, template-override

I want to override the phtml viewed_list.phtml file but I have not had any results, the file comes from the vendor folder:

> /vendor/magento/module-reports/view/frontend/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml

I want to modify part of the code and the adjustments are not seen, it does not enter, creating the file:

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Reports/templates/widget/viewed/content/viewed_list.phtml

any idea why the changes are not visible?

Thanks!

Comment: make sure theme in which you are overriding file is active and flush cache Or if you are in production mode, need to do content deploy as well!

Comment: Thanks for the comment but the theme is active, i flush cache and execute bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the wrong file, The template file for the recently viewed product is below.

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/web/template/product/list/listing.html
```

Override above file in the theme in below path.

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/web/template/product/list/listing.html
```

Comment: Thanks it works, i need to add a new discount price, can i do it with k.o. template?